# Iterate over each cell in a row RadGrid in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, tablecell

I have a Radgrid with few columns. In function`gv_OnItemDataBound` I want to iterate over every cell and change text style to bold.
I know how to do it when I know the unique name of column:

```
GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
TableCell tc = dataBoundItem["_Unique_Name"];
tc.Font.Bold = true;
```

But I'd like to just change font style for whole row without really having to access each cell by name. Is it possible?
PS: I do this change only for certain rows so I don't want to change it to bold in aspx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know how to get your [GridDataItem](http://docs.telerik.com/teststudioapi/html/T_Telerik_WebAii_Controls_Html_GridDataItem.htm). So, since you were successful in initializing `dataBoundItem`, nothing stops you from using `dataBoundItem.DataCells`, which is an `IList` property. From there on, you will be able to iterate that property, knowing that `Count` is the number of elements.

Comment: I just used `dataBoundItem.Cells` but it worked, thanks!

Comment: @eiKatte Cells is a member of ArtOfTest.WebAii.Controls.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow, while DataCells is a member of Telerik.WebAii.Controls.Html.GridDataItem. Telerik.WebAii.Controls.Html.GridDataItem is inherited from ArtOfTest.WebAii.Controls.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow, so both approaches should work.